# Copying multiple audio-streams with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I cut a sample from a `.m2ts-file` with multiple audio-streams?

I just managed to copy only one audio-stream

```
ffmpeg -i J:\BDMV\STREAM\00700.m2ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:32:52 -t 00:01:00 00700-sample.m2ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i J:\BDMV\STREAM\00700.m2ts -map 0 -c copy -ss 0:32:52 -t 00:01:00 00700-sample.m2ts
```

Without explicit mapping, ffmpeg picks one video, audio and subtitle stream from among all the inputs.

Comment: When I do the above, I get an error with **[NULL @ 000001eb4aa0c140] Unable to find a suitable output format for '0:32:52'**

Comment: Oops, corrected.